# How to Merge Textmate Windows?

Tags: macos, textmate, textmate-2

I accidentally double-clicked the tab header, and [TextMate](https://macromates.com/) moved the tab into a separate window. Is there some way to merge it back or disable the doubleclick nonsense altogether? I know about "Window" menu, but it has only the "Merge All Windows" option. Which would merge windows I don't want.

Comment: I'm afraid to say that merge all is all I know how to do :(. Closing projects and merging windows re-opening projects is the best I know how to do.

Comment: I've found a hack: cmd-atl-n to create a dummy tab, then drag and drop the tab header back into the original window's tab bar (not the text input area), and close the dummy tab. Still ideally a I want to disable the double click. It is very annoying.